# Show milliseconds with Android Chronometer

Tags: android, chronometer

I'm looking for a way to make the Chronometer in Android (preferably 1.6 and upwards) show 10ths of a second while counting up.

Is it possible to do this? If not, is there a free (and preferably open source) library that does the same? Failing that I'll write my own, but I'd rather use someone else's!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this?

Not really. You could pass a format string that shows tenths of a second, but the `Chronometer` itself only updates every second. The update frequency is baked into the code.

> If not, is there a free (and
>   preferably open source) library that
>   does the same?

The [`Chronometer` source](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-cts-9.0_r4/core/java/android/widget/Chronometer.java) is available under the Apache License 2.0, so you can modify it to suit. Find all occurrences of `1000` and change them to `100`, and you're probably most of the way there.

Bear in mind that this `Chronometer` can be used in an activity but not an app widget, since customized `View` classes are not supported by the app widget framework.

Comment: your link is not available anymore.

Answer (score 16):

Android's default chronometer widget does not support millisecond formatting.

I have modified the Chronometer widget source code in order to show milliseconds. Download it from [github](https://github.com/antoniom/Millisecond-Chronometer).

Answer (score 1):

I created an instance of a class that I built inside the `Activity`. This new class was an extension of the Android `CountDownTimer` class(add the implemented methods)

Here in the constructor you can add the duration in milliseconds and the interval to be 1/10 of a second, that is 100 milliseconds. In the `onTick` method, the commands are executed every 1/100th of a second for the given duration. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

[TimeCounter](https://github.com/hissaan/TimeCounter) is a library that does exactly the same. You won't have to worry about adding and subtracting time when you pause/resume your stop-watch. I am sure this will make your day.

Answer (score 0):

```
package ar.com.magiapensada.apps.dayoftheweek;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int NANOSECONDS_CONVERT = 1000000000;
    public static final int MICROSECONDS_CONVERT = 1000;
    public static final int SEXAGESIMA_CONVERT = 60;
    public static final int SEXAGESIMA_FORMAT_CONVERT = 2;
    public static final String BROADCAST_TIME_UPDATE = "BROADCAST_TIME_UPDATE";
    private Button start;
    private TextView tiempo;
    private long inicio;
    private Long terminado=null;
    private boolean running=false;
    private Button stop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.tiempo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tiempo);

        this.start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        this.stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

        BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action.equals(BROADCAST_TIME_UPDATE)) {

                    if ( terminado != null){
                        String cronometro = getCronometroValue(terminado);
                        tiempo.setText(cronometro);
                        terminado=null;
                    }else{
                        String cronometro = getCronometroValue(System.nanoTime());
                        tiempo.setText(cronometro);

                    }
                }


            }
        };
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_TIME_UPDATE));





        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.this.inicio = System.nanoTime();
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        running=true;
                        terminado=null;
                        while(running){
                            sendBroadcast();
                        }

                        sendBroadcast();

                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                terminado = System.nanoTime();
                running=false;

            }
        });

    }

    private void sendBroadcast() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_TIME_UPDATE);
        MainActivity.this.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private String getCronometroValue(long actual) {
        long dif = actual - MainActivity.this.inicio;

        long segundos = dif/ NANOSECONDS_CONVERT;
        long mili = dif - (segundos*NANOSECONDS_CONVERT);
        mili = mili/ MICROSECONDS_CONVERT;


        long minutos = segundos / SEXAGESIMA_CONVERT;
         segundos = segundos % SEXAGESIMA_CONVERT;

         String segString = formatSexagesima(segundos);
        String minutosString = formatSexagesima(minutos);

        String cronometro =  minutosString + ":" + segString + ":" + mili;
        return cronometro;
    }

    private String formatSexagesima(long value ){
        return String.format("%0" + SEXAGESIMA_FORMAT_CONVERT + "d", value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tiempo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stop" />


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have found the way after lots and lots of research. I don't know if it's effective or not, because the truth is that the Emulator crashes after about 10 seconds, but on the phone it runs just fine, and that does it for me. It looks something like this:

```
import android.os.Handler;
public class Chronometer extends Activity {
  private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
public void actions() {
  mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
  mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 1); //1 is the number of milliseconds you want the text to be updated
}
Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    i++;
    txt.setText(formatTime(i)); // formatTime is just for make it readable in HH:MM:SS:MS, but I assume you already have this
    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);
    }
  };
}
```