# Android: Chronometer with Milliseconds?

Tags: android, chronometer

What I want is to measure time with milliseconds, but using Chronometer has the problem that it has no accuracy (its most resolution is seconds)
I've seen this:
[Show miliseconds with Android Chronometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979835/show-milliseconds-with-android-chronometer)
But I haven't been able to make it work. Maybe I should use another Object? Any idea?

Comment: [Show miliseconds with Android Chronometer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979835/show-milliseconds-with-android-chronometer) what problem do you have with the code in the above link

Comment: Have you tried System.currentTimeMillis() ? Or does it not serve your purpose?

Comment: I'm testing it and it just not works. FormatTime? I don't have that function! Even if I try to show only "i" it crashes. I don't know what I'm doing wrong =(

Comment: This looks like it might work: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html I'll let you know

Comment: Using System.currentTimeMillis() and playing with it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is the easiest way: When you want to start the chrono:

```
StartTime=System.currentTimeMillis(); // I've defined StartTime as a double
```

Then, you just have to do compare current time with StartTime:

```
millis=System.currentTimeMillis()-StartTime; // Millis is a double too
// If you'd want seconds, add seconds=(int) milis/1000; etc.
```

And so you can play with milis (Has it arrive to the time I wanted? How many time is it counting? ...)