# Android: onCreate being invoked repeatedly

Tags: android

I have an activity in which i need to implement a basic mm::ss timer . Below is the code i have written for it. However the problem is that when i press the back button in the emulator and click on the app again, the values change much faster. It looks like the onCreate is being called again. How do i rectify this?
I have tried creating a boolean variable and setting it to true the first time the task is invoked . I call the startPeriodidUpdates() only when the value is false.But the onCreate creates the variable again with the value of false.

```
   public class GraphicsActivity extends Activity {
static int seconds = 0;
static int minutes = 0;
public static String time_elapsed;
public static boolean clearView = true;
Handler myhandler = new Handler();
public static String min,sec;  
public static boolean running = true;


   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
     startPeriodicUpdates();

    } 
    public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    } 
    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();    
    }
   public void onStop(){
   super.onStop();
    }

   public void startPeriodicUpdates()
   {
periodicCall();
   }
   public void stopPeriodicUpdates(){ 
     myhandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(myhandler);
   }

   public  void periodicCall()
    {

seconds++;
if(seconds ==60)
{
    seconds=0;
    minutes++;
    if(minutes==60)
    {
        seconds=0;
        minutes=0;
    }
}
// left-padding zeros to the minutes and seconds values
min = String.format("%02d",minutes);
sec = String.format("%02d",seconds);
time_elapsed =  min + ":" + sec;
time_elapsed =  min + ":" + sec + "";
myhandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        periodicCall();

    }
},1000);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help: The right way to do a peridic task is registering the handler in the `OnResume` and unregister in in `OnPause`. (You can unregister it other places, but OnPause is important)

Comment: Yes thats the right thing to do, but in my case i want the timer to be running in the back-ground even if i press the back-button in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I think its better if you use a Service for implementing your timer. Even if you push back button, the Service will continue running.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118855/android-chronometer-own-implementation) you can see a question I asked a bit time ago. You can see the implementation of a Custom Chronometer using a Service.

The activity where you want to receive the value of the Chronometer just need to have a BroadcastReceiver like:

```
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mMilis = intent.getLongExtra("milis",0);
        String time = intent.getStringExtra("tiempo");
        // Do Something with the time
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a solution to the problem above, but if you just want to update a view and count up form a given time, maybe have a look at [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html). If you want to count down and update views, you can do that with [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preference to use this method only once .

//pass true first time

```
 protected void storeSharedPrefs(Boolean value) {
        /*
         * Storing in Shared Preferences
         */
        editor.putString("first", value);
        editor.commit();  //Commiting changes
    }
```

Check each on time application is loaded, whether its the first time and configuration details has been entered correctly by checking SharedPreferences

```
private boolean first_time_check() {
        /* 
         * Checking Shared Preferences if the user had pressed 
         * */
        Boolean  first = uPreferences.getString("first", false);

            return first;
    }
```